# SQLAlchemy not marking session as dirty for changed attribute

Tags: sqlalchemy

When attempting to change an object loaded in with SQLAlchemy, the `session.dirty` object is not behaving the way I'd expect:

```
o = sqla.session.query(sqla.Game).first()
  <sqla.Game at 0x7fdcc1f707b8>
o.wiki
 <null>
o.wiki = 'test'
o.wiki
  'test'
sqla.session.is_modified(o)
  False
sqla.session.dirty
  IdentitySet([])    
inspect(o).attrs['wiki'].history
  History(added=(), unchanged=['test'], deleted=())
```

Committing this to the database does in fact update it, but I'm really unclear on why it's marked as "unchanged". If I modify a relationship on the object, that does properly show in the "new" and "deleted" areas in history. I'm loading the models in via automap, and the session does not have autocommit on.

I have also tried manually calling `flag_modified`, and specifying the column directly (without automap) to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Annnd I figured it out. I had `autoflush` on by default. Turning it to False fixed the issue.